# Easy way on archiving record with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want not to delete record from DB, but just copy it to archive table just to avoid accidents.
What I found out is we can use custom stored procedure. But we cannot just add a delete stored procedure, we have to add stored procedure for select and update also.
Is there any built-in or easier way on doing that? 
I just need to keep the deleted records, just in case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go with a separate archive table, and a trigger on deletion from the regular table, something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Foo_AD
ON  dbo.Foo
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert Archive_Foo (a, b)
        select a, b from deleted
END
GO
```

Comment: That's what I though. How should we handle relationships and cascade deletes in this case?

Comment: I suppose that depends on what you want out of these archive tables. If you're expecting to use them, and query them regularly, even hook them up to EF, then I don't know the best way to go. But if you just want to keep the data strictly as an emergency backup so you don't lose it, I'd say just skip the foreign keys completely, and let the records fall into these archive tables as-is.