# Entity framework where Deleted = 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to add this simple statement to each SQL query, per table:

> WHERE Deleted = 0

Is there any easy way of doing? I mean I need to filter all records, preferrably in the edmx file.

Comment: @Darin I have an instead of dlete trigger that sets deleted to 1. So now I just need to filter records not to include delted records.

Comment: Have you considered just using a view for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to add a WHERE to your object sets by default. I don't know if you can do that by default, but a couple ways I can think of to accomplish this are:

1) Use views to give you the WHERE clause and build your entities off the views. I've never actually done this, so I don't know how well views work with EF - if you need to write back to the database, this probably wouldn't work well.

2) Create new properties in a partial class of your EDMX, like:

```
partial class MyEntities
{
    public IQueryable<Foo> ActiveFoos
    {
        return Foos.Where(f => f.Deleted == 0);
    }
}
...
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var foo = context.ActiveFoos.Where(f => f.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

3) Create a child context class and `new` out the properties - kind of ugly, but this would be reasonably transparent to the developer once it's built.

```
public class CustomEntities : MyEntities
{
    public new IQueryable<Foo> Foos
    {
        get { return base.Foos.Where(f => f.Deleted == 0); }
    }
}
...
using (var context = new CustomEntities())
{
    var foo = context.Foos.Where(f => f.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: @Joe Enos -

You can just do 

    context.Foos.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == 1);

Instead of

    context.Foos.Where(f => f.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey Good call. I generally use the `.Where` method even if it's not necessary, since it's easier to modify (adding more `Where`'s, `OrderBy`'s, etc.), but this would be a pretty common scenario where your syntax would be cleaner.

Comment: @user194076 One thing these wouldn't do is apply to all tables automatically. For that, you may need to do some extra work - maybe using T4 templates instead of using the out-of-the-box code for your context. I've never done it, so I don't know the workload involved, but if it's something you're interested in, you can look into that technique.

Comment: @Joe Enos:  I just have 10 tables, so I don't think it will be pain. Can you please point me to the tutorial or something that can show how to actually add this partial class thing? I just cannot figure out where to paste the code from you example?

Comment: @user194076: The MSDN documentation explains it pretty well - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx). Basically, the pre-built context class is already marked as partial, so you can add a new code file anywhere you want, and add a class with the same name (and namespace), mark it partial, and you're adding on to the pre-built class. It lets you add additional methods without editing an automatically generated codefile.

Comment: @user194076: One more thing that just came to me - these will work when you're getting single objects directly from the DB. But when you start getting related items (using navigation properties, like `context.Cars.Include("Driver")` or `myCar.Driver.Name`), these filters won't apply. You'd either have to use the same technique to override the navigation properties, or use the T4 templates, or just avoid navigation properties altogether and always query single tables.

Comment: @Joe Enos Oh, i got it. This seems like a lot of mess. Probably there's an easier way on keeping deleted records with EF and sql server. If you have easier suggestion on that, please let me know. I've also set up a post(empty): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274395/easy-way-on-archiving-record-with-ef

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way to ensure that `Deleted = 0` is used always (including lazy loading, explicit loading and eager loading) is using [Conditional mapping](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94784/Using-Conditional-Mapping-in-Entity-Framework). The drawback of conditional mapping is that `Deleted` column will not be available in the entity = Delete operation which sets this column must be mapped to stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it at the time you get your results from EntityFramework.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<TableEntity> filteredResults = TableEntityName.Where(t => t.Delete = 0);
```